# Xaml unhandled exception popup not appearing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hey I am having an issue with my error handling. Basically I am trying to show a popup allowing the user to input any steps they took when an unhandled exception happens. I can do it fine if I write it as a regular c# popup but this is not the case if I create the popup in xaml. If I create it in xaml I am getting a
"our app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code" message and the application closes.

Now if I add the popup to an onclick event it shows up correctly.

```
 AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
 UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ShowExceptionPopUp);
```

And the show ExceoptionPopUp method

```
   ErrorPopup error = new ErrorPopup(sender, e);
```

And inside the ErrorPop class

```
  InitializeComponent();
        this.errorSender = errorSender;
        this.eventArgs = eventArgs;
```

If I step through it finishes on InitializeComponent(). I am wondering could someone shed some light on this issue for me?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you want this done in XAML? I would do something like that is the code behind.

Comment: To keep styling and coding consistent is the main reason......... Otherwise I'd make a normal c# popup

Comment: When it comes to popups and such, i want full control, and that is hard in XAML. Hence why i would stick it in code behind. Its easier to adjust and extend in code behind too. I would create a `Window` control that takes input to display the message, and open it as a Dialog from Code Behind. I know im not helping your answer, but if you are just trying to do everything in XAML for asthetics and consistency, you may be overthinking your solution.

Comment: I did try to go down a similar path before, and eventually found it more frustrating than helpful. Hence, why i put it in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I fixed in the end. The isssue was that the resources were multi threading and a xaml ui can be only be single threaded. Painfully annoying to fix but all good. Thanks for the help